Is a "logical argument" a "rule of inference", and an "inference rule" the same thing?
Difference sources and diciplines use different terminologies, but they all seem to describe the same logical structure like the following:
Premise 1
Premise 2
...
---------
Conclusion

So are all those terms describe the same thing? Or do they have some subtle differences?

No, logical arguments and inference rules are not the same.
An Inference Rule is a schema specifying a class of particular inference steps that share a common form. For example, consider the inference rule Modus Ponens (MP).
(MP) from $\phi\to \psi$ and $\phi$, infer $\psi$.
Here $\phi$ and $\psi$ are meta-variables that range over particular sentences of the logical language in question, so range over things like $p,\ p\wedge q,\ r\to s$ to name a few. (MP) is schematic in the sense that by substituting particular sentences, say $p$ and $q$, for $\phi$ and $\psi$, respectively, we obtain a particular instance of the rule like following instance of (MP)
$(1)\ p\to q\hspace{1.6cm} \text{ (Pr.)}\\ (2)\ p\hspace{2.5cm} \text{ (Pr.)}\\ \\ (3)\ q \hspace{2.5cm} \text{ (from 1 and 2 by MP)}$.
On the other hand, a Logical Argument is a chain (really a tree) of inferences from a set of premises to a conclusion where each inference is an instance of an inference rule.
A degenerate example is a particular instance of an inference rule, like above. Maybe such an example is the source of confusion. Another example, which is composed of multiple instances of (MP), is the following.
$(1)\ p\to (r\to q) \hspace{.3cm} \text{ (Pr.)}\\ (2)\ p\hspace{2.5cm} \text{ (Pr.)}\\ \\ (3)\ r \hspace{2.5cm} \text{ (Pr.)}\\ (4)\ r\to q \hspace{1.6cm} \text{ (from 1 and 2 by MP)}\\ (5)\ q \hspace{2.5cm} \text{ (from 4 and 3 by MP)}$.

Not exactly.
An argument "is a series of sentences, statements, or propositions some of which are called premises and one is the conclusion. The purpose of an argument is to give reasons for one's conclusion via justification, explanation, and/or persuasion.
A rule of inference, in deductive reasoning, is an instruction which takes premises and produces a conclusion.
See e.g. Modus Ponens and see also What is the accurate definition of inference rule?
